# Route classic ASP Urls to MVC routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp-classic, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I created a custom router in my MVC project like this:

```
public class Classic_ASP_Routes : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        const string status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        var response = httpContext.Response;
        var legacyUrl = request.Url.ToString();
        var newUrl = "";

        if (legacyUrl.Contains("eventdetail.asp"))
        {
            // grab the ID from the query string
            int id = int.Parse(legacyUrl.Split('=')[1]);

            newUrl = "/event/" + id;
        }
        else if(legacyUrl.Contains("addeent.asp"))
        {
            newUrl = "/Calendar/Add-Event";
        }

        if (newUrl.Length > 0)
        {
            response.Status = status;
            response.RedirectLocation = newUrl;
            response.End();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then included it in my routes.config like this:

```
routes.Add("ClassicASP", new Classic_ASP_Routes());
```

And at one time, this WAS working on a dev server running IIS 7.5  I had to fiddle with the IIS handler mappings, but it eventually worked, parsing legaxy asp urls and correctly extracting querystring parameters.

But alas, it seems if I touch the IIS settings at all, the handler mapping setting somehow reverts.  I can now now longer get the handler to map correctly, I swear I will write it down if I get it working again.

Comment: You're better off using the IIS url rewrite module than trying to do it within MVC

Comment: @John Not shown, is that I need to look up one of the params to create the new url, is that possible in url rewrite

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean there.  URL rewrite rules do accept variables, eg if you have a detail page`http://mysite/article.asp?articleid=n` you can create one rule which rewrites that as `http://mysite/article/n` - you don't need a separate rule for each value of 'n'

Comment: No I mean the new urls are seo friendly, so will include city, state, title

Comment: Are city, state and title passed as querystring values in your legacy pages or do they come from somewhere else?

Comment: Nope, legacy urls just have id

Comment: Obviously you can have wildcards in rewrite rules, but the rewrite module can't query your database, that will need either Classic ASP or ASP.net